# Why postfix is used more often than prefix expression?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, mathematical-analysis, stacks

i was reading stack and i came across the infix, preifx and postfix expression.So i understood that why postfix /prefix expressions are preferred over infix expression ( due to its unambiguous nature) .But i am not getting any enough information  about the popularity reason of postifx expression over prefix expression.

**Why are we not using prefix expression than the postfix expression more often?**

**I am guessing that** ,

1. it's related to the easiness of converting the infix to postfix
2. or the evaulation process of postifx is easy than prefix.

*If so, Please someone elaborate on it.*

thanks.

Comment: Functional programming languages use prefix.

Comment: The only reason I am aware of is, "because HP made a bunch of calculators that used postfix notation."

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation is easier for postfix-notation expressions.

The evaluation is done easily using a stack. The expression is processed from left to right, one token at a time:

- operand -> put it on the stack;
- operator -> get from the stack the number of values it needs (two for `+`, three for `?:`, one for unary `-` and so on), combine the values using the operator and put the result on the stack.
- when the entire expression is processed, the stack contains only one value; it is the value of the entire expression.

The prefix-notation expressions can be evaluated using [a similar algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation#Evaluation_algorithm) that uses the operands (instead of the operators) to trigger computations. However, it is not that straight-forward; it involves lookups on the top of the stack to find the operator and to decide if enough operands were read for it.

The prefix-notation expressions can also be evaluated from right to left using the same algorithm as for postfix-notation expressions.